# Move List<Integer> element to end of list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an ArrayList whose first three elements I want to move to the end of the list. I use 'set' but it's not working as expected:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Integer i : integers) {
    int index = integers.indexOf(i);
    if(index==0 || index==1 || index==2) {
        integers.set(i, integers.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `subList()` and `addAll()` method appropriately

Comment: that will just add and not replace the elements. Remove throws ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: you don't need to iterate or remove(), see javadoc

Comment: Make sure to call `removeAll()` before `addAll()` to remove those elements.

Comment: While this answer offers the best approach, I believe it is too vague to be extremely helpful in its current state.  +1 regardless.

Comment: @Vulcan. I think, this is appropriate as for giving jus an idea of what to do.

Comment: aha, and what if the elements are not in order (0,1,2) but are taken by value (i.e. remove all elements with value 3 in the list).

Comment: @user584513. I don't understand. What has order to do here, since you want just the first three elements to be removed? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: *"what if the elements are not in order"*  That is a separate question that you should ask on a ..separate question.

Answer (score 15):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Use: `Collections.rotate(integers, -3);`

For reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29

Comment: This will reverse the order of the elements, won't it? Not sure if it matters.

Comment: No, it won't reverse the order of the elements

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int index=0;index<3;index++){
    integers.add(integers.get(0));
    integers.remove(0);
}
```

I think this ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The set method works at least as described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

> integers.set(i, integers.size()-1);

Changes your list by setting the value integers.size()-1 at the position i of your list :)

I think the Collections.rotate is the best solution but you could also add the first element of the list to its end and then remove the first element and repeat 3 times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    integers.add(integers.get(0));
    integers.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As the first answer, the form would be:

```
List<Integer> auxList = originalList.subList(0, 3);
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++) {originalList.remove(i);}
originalList.addAll(auxList);
```

Comment: Should be `subList(0, 3)` and you need to call `removeAll(auxList)` before the `addAll(auxList)` call.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use add() to put them at the end and then delete the old element? The exception is due to the iterator being used after the list was modified. The answer is to save the three items using the iterator and then modify the list outside of the iterator.

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer keep[] = new Integer[3];

for(Integer i : integers) {
    int index = integers.indexOf(i);
    if(index==0 || index==1 || index==2) {
        keep[i] = i;  // save the first three
    }
}

// add the first three to the end of the list
integers.add(keep[0]);
integers.add(keep[1]);
integers.add(keep[2]);


// remove the previous first three
integers.remove(0);
integers.remove(1);      
integers.remove(2);
```

I'm wondering if you need to do a `integers.remove(0)` three times depending on whether the 0'th element is reclaimed or left empty.

Comment: This will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @Kelly looking at the javadoc or even trying it would answer your question (you have to remove(0) three times). And your code is becoming really complicated. Your previous attempt throw-ed an exception because the for-each loop internally uses an iterator...

Comment: I had just closed the javadoc when the thought occurred. The first rule of engineering is "get it working, _THEN_ make it pretty".

Comment: @KellyS.French I agree and frankly I know the answer because I first tested the remove(0) remove(1) remove(2) solution just to see it doesn't work because after every remove the list elements are shifted so once you remove(0) the previous element at position 1 now has position 0...